Match and list values to a list including mutliple column criteria



0
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J
K
L
M
N




1
Products

Shop

2023-S
2023-M

2024-S
2024-M







2
















3
Product A

shop3

80
2%

500
22%

ColCrit1
ColCrit2

lookup_array


4
Product B

shop2

320
23%

180
60%

Product D
shop1

2024-s


5
Product B

shop1

90
8%

300
36%

Product G
shop3

return_array


6
Product C

shop3

500
15%

657
16%




Products


7
Product D

shop1

160
17%

500
15%







8
Product D

shop1

500
30%

600
8%

list
match




9
Product D

shop1

130
4%

300
4%

830
Product G




10
Product E

shop2

75
10%

450
10%

600
Product D




11
Product F

shop4

60
8%

370
4%

600
Product G




12
Product F

shop1

500
11%

850
4%

500
Product D




13
Product G

shop3

350
8%

150
15%

300
Product D




14
Product G

shop3

60
47%

600
7%

300
Product G




15
Product G

shop3

90
25%

830
35%

300
Product G




16
Product G

shop2

390
9%

325
13%

150
Product G




17
Product G

shop3

170
30%

300
9%







18
Product G

shop3

320
5%

300
12%







19
Product H

shop2

935
27%

230
16%







20
Product I

shop3

134
18%

600
42%









In Range K9:K16 all values from Column H which fullfill the column criteria in Range K4:K6 and Range L4:L6 are listed. 
In Range L9:L16 I want to add the column value based on a variable return_array entered in Cell N6.
With reference to this quesion  I have been able to develop this formula:
=IFERROR(LET(
     a; K9:K17;
     b; A1:I1;
     c; A3:I20;
     d; XLOOKUP(N4;b;c;"");
     MAP(a;LAMBDA(α; @DROP(TOCOL(FILTER(IFS(d=α;IF(c=0;x;c));N6=b);3);
     COUNTIF(K9:α;α)-1))));"")

This solution almost works perfectly.

However, the issue now are the values in Cell H3 and Cell H5. These values are equal with some values in Range K9:K16. 
Therefore, they are considered in the above formula and the list in Range L9:L16 is not correct. 
In order to solve this issue I think the column criteria in Range K4:K6 and Range L4:L6 somehow must be added to the formula above.
Do you have any idea how to do that?

=SORT(FILTER(CHOOSECOLS(A3:I20,XMATCH(N4,A1:I1),XMATCH(N6,A1:I1)),COUNTIFS(K4:K6,A3:A20,L4:L6,C3:C20)),,-1)
A simple COUNTIFS could be used as the filter criteria for a FILTER on the columns you like to be returned using CHOOSECOLS including XMATCH.

Formula almost works. However, when for example colcrit1 (K4:K6) or colcrit2 (L4:L6) is empty it gives #CALC! error.

Yes, because there's no arguments to filter against. What would you expect in such case? Blank? =SORT(FILTER(CHOOSECOLS(A3:I20,XMATCH(N4,A1:I1),XMATCH(N6,A1:I1)),COUNTIFS(K4:K6,A3:A20,L4:L6,C3:C20),""),,-1)

Thanks for the answer. Got your point. Opened a new question for it.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78717418/match-and-list-values-to-a-dynamic-list-including-mutliple-column-criteria

You can use COUNTIFS to filter out lookup array and return array:
=LET(
    included, COUNTIFS(K4:K5, A3:A20, L4:L5, C3:C20),
    lookup_array, FILTER(XLOOKUP(N4, A1:I1, A3:I20, ""), included, ""),
    return_array, FILTER(XLOOKUP(N6, A1:I1, A3:I20, ""), included, ""),
    selected, K9:K16,
    MAP(
        selected,
        LAMBDA(x,
            LET(
                filtered, FILTER(return_array, lookup_array = x, ""),
                current_count, COUNTIF(K9:x, x),
                INDEX(filtered, MIN(current_count, ROWS(filtered)), 1)
            )
        )
    )
)


European (;) format:
=LET(
    included; COUNTIFS(K4:K5; A3:A20; L4:L5; C3:C20);
    lookup_array; FILTER(XLOOKUP(N4; A1:I1; A3:I20; ""); included; "");
    return_array; FILTER(XLOOKUP(N6; A1:I1; A3:I20; ""); included; "");
    selected; K9:K16;
    MAP(
        selected;
        LAMBDA(x;
            LET(
                filtered; FILTER(return_array; lookup_array = x; "");
                current_count; COUNTIF(K9:x; x);
                INDEX(filtered; MIN(current_count; ROWS(filtered)); 1)
            )
        )
    )
)


I'm in Europe and not all use the ";", but that probably comes from working with 90 nationalities teaching them Excel...

Not sure what the correct terminology is. I will just call it ";" format from now on.

Hey, could you improve this so that when items in K4:K5 are not found in return array? For example if Product G is misspelt, for the second 600 in selected,  filtered will return only one 600 and INDEX(filtered, current_count = 2, 1) results in error.

@nkalvi, changed to INDEX(filtered, MIN(current_count, ROWS(filtered)), 1)

Hope this link works: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AjsOQOZMdif-kjP8aNLIWu1hx-DJ?e=ScVKbR

@rachel, results are not correct with INDEX(filtered, MIN(current_count, ROWS(filtered)), 1) either, though no errors. For example, it gives 6 rows of 'Product D' with K4:K6 = (Product D, Product).

@nkalvi, I recall she said in her previous post that frequency of "selected data" will be the same as the frequency of the original data. but if it really bothers you, you can use if (ROWS(filtered)<current_count, "", index(filtered, current_count,1))

I'm sorry @rachel, I didn't view this in the context of the previous postings also. No, it doesn't bother me at all. I like the candor of your answers.

Extending from P.b's
=LET(
    filtered, FILTER(
        CHOOSECOLS(
            A3:I20,
            XMATCH(N4, A1:I1),
            XMATCH(N6, A1:I1)
        ),
        COUNTIFS(K4:K6, A3:A20, L4:L6, C3:C20)
    ),
    freq, LAMBDA(arr,
        MAP(
            SEQUENCE(ROWS(arr)),
            LAMBDA(i,
                SUM(--(TAKE(arr, i) = INDEX(arr, i, )))
            )
        )
    ),
    TOCOL(
        XLOOKUP(
            K9:K16 & " " & freq(K9:K16),
            CHOOSECOLS(filtered, 1) & " " &
                freq(CHOOSECOLS(filtered, 1)),
            CHOOSECOLS(filtered, 2)
        ),
        2
    )
)



I missed out on the result_array argument being a dynamical input. Updated that in my answer.

Ah, yes, I also missed it. thank you @P.b. I'll update by answer to reflect the change :) BTW would you have a shorter method for getting running counts?

Running counts of what? (Would SCAN or MAP be good choices of weapon?)

Running count of values, for example 600 1, 600 2, 400 1, 400 2 etc. I'm using MAP along with SUM + IF  here. Since you and @JvdV have many concise methods, I was wondering about other compact ways.

Thanks for the compliment. Hard to tell without data, but something along the lines: =let(r,range,map(r,lambda(x,sum(n(@r:x=x)))))

Thanks - using @ gives warning on Mac; I shortened SUM + IF to SUM only in my answer.

@r would refer to the range start. It could be A2 for instance: =let(r,A2:A10,map(r,lambda(x,sum(n(A2:x=x)))))

I know, I am late, and the reason for this, I completely missed the typo in ColCrit1, both P.b Sir, and Rachel (Got the data from her, shared an excel link in the comments), clarified the issue in the context of the OP.
I had the same idea of using COUNTIFS(), but since I was struggling with the typo which I was unaware or my mistake of overlooking it, hence couldn't post in real time, also instead of using COUNTIFS() which has already been used in all the above answers, here is my alternative with keeping the original formula intact as in OP, uses XMATCH()+ISNA()+1 combination aka XMATCH()+ISNUMBER():


• Formula used in cell L9
=LET(
     a, K9:K16,
     b, A1:I1,
     c, A3:I20,
     d, XLOOKUP(N4,b,c,""),
     MAP(a,LAMBDA(α, @DROP(TOCOL(FILTER(IFS((d=α)*
                    (1-ISNA(XMATCH(A3:A20,K4:K5)+XMATCH(C3:C20,L4:L5))),
                    IF(c=0,x,c)),N6=b,""),3),
     COUNTIF(K9:α,α)-1))))



Formula almost works. However, when for example colcrit1 (K4:K6) or colcrit2 (L4:L6) is empty it gives #CALC! error.

@Michi so what should be the output at that scenario, do you want to return blank.

Got your point. Opened a new question for it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78717418/match-and-list-values-to-a-dynamic-list-including-mutliple-column-criteria
