Match and list values to a dynamic list including multiple column criteria



0
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J
K
L
M
N




1
Products

Shop

2023-S
2023-M

2024-S
2024-M







2
















3
Product A

shop3

80
2%

500
22%

ColCrit1
ColCrit2

lookup_array


4
Product B

shop2

320
23%

180
60%

Product D
shop1

2024-s


5
Product B

shop1

90
8%

300
36%

Product G
shop3

return_array


6
Product C

shop3

500
15%

657
16%




Products


7
Product D

shop1

160
17%

500
15%







8
Product D

shop1

500
30%

600
8%

list
match




9
Product D

shop1

130
4%

300
4%

830
Product G




10
Product E

shop2

75
10%

450
10%

600
Product D




11
Product F

shop4

60
8%

370
4%

600
Product G




12
Product F

shop1

500
11%

850
4%

500
Product D




13
Product G

shop3

350
8%

150
15%

300
Product D




14
Product G

shop3

60
47%

600
7%

300
Product G




15
Product G

shop3

90
25%

830
35%

300
Product G




16
Product G

shop2

390
9%

325
13%

150
Product G




17
Product G

shop3

170
30%

300
9%







18
Product G

shop3

320
5%

300
12%







19
Product H

shop2

935
27%

230
16%







20
Product I

shop3

134
18%

600
42%









In Range K9:K16 all values from Column H which fullfill the column criteria in Range K4:K6 and Range L4:L6 are listed based on this formula:
=SORT(
    LET(
    a;COUNTIF(K4:K6;A1:A20)+AND(K4:K6="");
    b;COUNTIF(L4:L6;C1:C20)+AND(L4:L6="");
    FILTER(FILTER(A1:J20;(A1:J1=N4);"");a*b;""));;-1)

In Range L9:L16 I want to :

match the values accordingly to the results from Range K9:K16 and
the column entered as variable return_array in Cell N6.

The formulas from this question already come close to the result:
Option 1
=CHOOSECOLS(SORT(FILTER(CHOOSECOLS(A3:I20;XMATCH(N4;A1:I1);XMATCH(N6;A1:I1));COUNTIFS(K4:K6;A3:A20;L4:L6;C3:C20));;-1);2)

Option 2
=LET(
     a, K9:K16,
     b, A1:I1,
     c, A3:I20,
     d, XLOOKUP(N4,b,c,""),
     MAP(a,LAMBDA(α, @DROP(TOCOL(FILTER(IFS((d=α)*
                    (1-ISNA(XMATCH(A3:A20,K4:K6)+XMATCH(C3:C20,L4:L6))),
                    IF(c=0,x,c)),N6=b,""),3),
     COUNTIF(K9:α,α)-1))))

However, when for example Range K4:K6 or Range L4:L6 is empty and the list in Range K9:K16 is adjusted to it both formulas for Range L9:L16 return error #CALC!?
How do I need to modify them to make them adjusting based on the list in Range K4:K6?

Also, better to clarify how you want to apply ColCrit1 and ColCrit2. e.g. do you want rows where (Product = D and Shop =1)  OR (Product = G and Shop =3) or where (Product = D or G) AND (shop = 1 or 3).

COUNTIF(K4:K6;A1:A20) * COUNTIF(L4:L6;C1:C20) means (Product = D or G) AND (shop = 1 or 3); while COUNTIFS means (Product = D and Shop =1)  OR (Product = G and Shop =3). I noticed all the answers you received assume the former. Hopefully that is what you want.

I think you mean if empty than list all?
In that case:
=SORT(FILTER(CHOOSECOLS(A3:I20,XMATCH(N4,A1:I1),XMATCH(N6,A1:I1)),(AND(K4:K6="")+COUNTIF(K4:K6,A3:A20))*(AND(L4:L6="")+COUNTIF(L4:L6,C3:C20)),""),,-1)
Or:
=LET(x,LAMBDA(a,b,AND(a="")+COUNTIF(a,b)),
SORT(FILTER(CHOOSECOLS(A3:I20,XMATCH(N4,A1:I1),XMATCH(N6,A1:I1)),x(K4:K6,A3:A20)*x(L4:L6,C3:C20)),,-1))


Maybe I have not understood clearly, if both the ColCrits are empty then why not return the outputs based on the lookup_array and return_array whilst matching the list accordingly, how does returning the whole column H helps in that scenario, is not deviating from the other conditions?:


=LET(
     a, K9:K16,
     b, A1:I1,
     c, A3:I20,
     d, XLOOKUP(N4,b,c,""),
     e, (1-ISNA(XMATCH(A3:A20,K4:K6)*XMATCH(C3:C20,L4:L6))),
     MAP(a,LAMBDA(α, @DROP(TOCOL(FILTER(IFS(IF(SUM(e)=0,(d=α),(d=α)*e),
                                            IF(c=0,x,c)),N6=b,""),3),
     COUNTIF(K9:α,α)-1))))


Update:


=LET(
     a, K9:K16,
     b, A1:I1,
     c, A3:I20,
     d, XLOOKUP(N4,b,c,""),
     e, (1-ISNA(XMATCH(A3:A20&"|"&C3:C20,K4:K6&"|"&L4:L6))),
     IFERROR(MAP(a,LAMBDA(α, @DROP(TOCOL(FILTER(IFS(IF(SUM(e)=0,(d=α),(d=α)*e),
                                                    IF(c=0,x,c)),N6=b,""),3),
     COUNTIF(K9:α,α)-1))),""))



The solution works when CoCrti1 and ColCrit2 are both empty. If only one of them is empty the list is not matcthing with Ragne K9:K16.

@Michi see the update is that what you are asking for?
